# есть массив с фотками для background! Нужно каким-то образом каждых 5 секунд менять картинку для заднего фона для div className galleryWrapper

Tags: reactjs

```js
import React, {FC, useState} from 'react';
import UserLink from "../UI/UserLink/UserLink";
import FormBooking from "../FormBooking/FormBooking";
import styles from "./Gallery.module.scss"

interface GalleryProps {
    ///props
}

const Gallery: FC<GalleryProps> = ({}) => {
    // state to change background
    const [background, setBackground] = useState([
        "https://www.advancetemplate.com/assets/zip/070069c9c3e3addaf305d3ff472958bc/sona/img/hero/hero-3.jpg",
        "https://www.advancetemplate.com/assets/zip/070069c9c3e3addaf305d3ff472958bc/sona/img/hero/hero-2.jpg",
        "https://www.advancetemplate.com/assets/zip/070069c9c3e3addaf305d3ff472958bc/sona/img/hero/hero-1.jpg"
    ]);

    /// IN utils folder mb

   // const changeBack = (delay: number) => {
   //     setInterval(() => {
   //          for (let i = 0; i < background.length; i++) {
   //              setBackground(background[i])
   //                  }
   //      }, delay)
   //          }

    return (
        <div className={styles.galleryWrapper}>
            <div className={styles.sona}>
                <div className={styles.containerSona}>
                    <h2 className={styles.headline}> Sona A Luxury Hotel </h2>
                    <p
                        className={styles.description}
                    >
                        Here are the best hotel booking sites, including recommendations for international
                        travel and for finding low-priced hotel rooms.
                    </p>

                    <UserLink
                        linkCaption="Discover Now"
                    />
                </div>
                <div className={styles.formWrapper}>
                    <FormBooking
                        title="Booking Your Hotel"
                    />
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    );
};

export default Gallery;
```

Comment: В ваш div добавьте style с background-image: url(background[num]), а num сделайте переменной через useState. далее в хуке useEffect запустите интервал в которм num будет меняться

Comment: а что означает "num через useState" как это должно выглядеть

Comment: counst [num, setNum] = useState(0) <- начальное значение. Когда меняете картинку, вызывайте setNum('Новый номер картинки(индекс массива (background)')

Comment: а можно фрагментом кода показать

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Для того, что бы организовать ротацию изображений фона элементов в React компонентах, нужно запустить функцию смены изображений, например на основе setInterval() :

```
export default function App() {
  // Здесь лежит массив с фоновыми изображениями
  const [background, setBackground] = useState([
    "https://www.advancetemplate.com/assets/zip/070069c9c3e3addaf305d3ff472958bc/sona/img/hero/hero-3.jpg",
    "https://www.advancetemplate.com/assets/zip/070069c9c3e3addaf305d3ff472958bc/sona/img/hero/hero-2.jpg",
    "https://www.advancetemplate.com/assets/zip/070069c9c3e3addaf305d3ff472958bc/sona/img/hero/hero-1.jpg"
  ]); 
  // Здесь будет лежать индекс элемента массива с изображениями
  const [num, setNum] = useState(0);

useEffect(() => {
  // Запускаем интервал для ротации изображений
  const timer = setInterval(() => {
    // Сохраняем значение в стейт
    setNum(prevNum => {
      let n = prevNum;
      if (n === background.length - 1) {
        n = 0;
      } else {
        n++;
      }
      return n;
    });
  }, 1000);
  // Когда компонент будет отмонтирован, он удалит таймер
  return () => {
    clearInterval(timer);
  }
}, []);

  return (
    <div>
      <div style={{backgroundImage: `url(${background[num]})`}}></div>
    </div>
  );
}
```

Comment: спасибо большое